# Obliterate changelist containing modified files

Tags: perforce

If I obliterate a changelist or a file revision will I still be able to sync later revisions?

I ask because perforce shows diff against the previous revision and if that gets obliterated will the later revisions come?

```
eg% p4 describe 400648

Differences ...

==== //releases/version.xml#135 (text) ====

4c4
<   <build build="71">
---
>   <build build="72">
```

So if I obliterate #134 or the changelist containing it, will I be able to sync #135 and later revisions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to sync later versions.  The p4 obliterate page http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/obliterate.html says it will only obliterate the version(s) you specify:

> If you specify a single revision (for instance, p4 obliterate file#3),
>   only that revision of the file is obliterated. If you specify a
>   revision range (for instance, p4 obliterate file#3,5), only the
>   revisions in that range are obliterated.

This example from the same page shows that obliterated versions will no longer exist to Perforce, but later versions will:

> Obliterating files in revision ranges can also change the behavior of
>   scripts, as revision numbers of files may "skip" obliterated
>   revisions. For instance, the output of p4 filelog after obliterating
>   revisions #2 and #3 might look like this:

```
... #4 change 1276 edit on 2011/04/18 by user@dev1 (binary) 'Fixed'
... #1 change 1231 add on 2011/04/12 by user@dev1 (binary) 'First try'
```